# How to draw wavy line on iOS device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios

I have many points constructing a line.  How can I draw a wavy line through those points?

Answer (score 9):

Use CGContextRef on iOS.

WavyView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface WavyView : UIView {

}

@end
```

WavyView.m

```
#import "WavyView.h"

@implementation WavyView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);
    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 100, 100);
    CGContextAddCurveToPoint(context,125,150,175,150,200,100);
    CGContextAddCurveToPoint(context,225,50,275,75,300,200);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Result:

[image: The Wave]

Comment: I am trying to put this WavyView into a ViewController but when I add it to the UIViewController all I get is a black square. Here is the code i use WavyView *drawScreen = [[WIALines alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(170, 351, 100, 100)];
    [self.view addSubview:drawScreen]; What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7):

Example:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect
{
    NSBezierPath *curve = [NSBezierPath bezierPath];
    [curve moveToPoint:NSMakePoint(0,50)];
    [curve relativeCurveToPoint:NSMakePoint(150,50) controlPoint1:NSMakePoint(50,100) controlPoint2:NSMakePoint(100,0)]; 
    [[NSColor redColor] set];
    [curve stroke];
}
```

Result:

[image: Curve.png]

Comment: NSBezierPath was in AppKit framework which was not a part of ios sdk but for the mac, so what can i do?

Comment: Use CGContextRef instead, see my new answer including example.

Answer (score -1):

create a `NSBezierPath` , and use your points as the control points.