# how to draw a ton of lines and shapes in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, performance, drawing, lines

i am using objective c the last 5 months. so now i would
 like to make an application which the user has the ability to draw a ton of lines with interaction(for example finger swipes).

So i started to use drawrect method and Core graphics library.  So i made an array which holds the CGPoints and  in calling of [self setNeedsDisplay]  the appi redrawed the whole screen from the start (for loop in drawrect-because i need in TouchesMoved the ability to draw and erase the line during finger movement). When the array had over for example 1000 lines then there was a problem because the response was to slow.

In addition seeking for a better performance, i made some methods to draw each line in a view and then add this view (using CGBitmapContextCreate, uiimageview), (For TouchesMOved the appi was removing the previous view and adding the new one each time).

Unfortunately the results were the same. The performance was to bad while adding more & more context(lines, shapes, etc) on canvas.

I should be grateful if you would answer to this query.
Which technique is the best for drawing a ton of lines on canvas? Cocos 2d is an option? Open gl is my last option and i would prefer a solution which is near at coreGraphics library. Is there a way using core Graphics to have the same performance in drawing the first line and in drawing the 1000th line?

Sorry for my english..:(

update 15/06/12
below is the code. i used some ideas of Dimitris from this post:

[Drawing incrementally in a UIView (iPhone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798414/drawing-incrementally-in-a-uiview-iphone)

```
- (BOOL) initContext:(CGSize)size {

    int bitmapByteCount;
    int bitmapBytesPerRow;


    bitmapBytesPerRow = (size.width * 4);
    bitmapByteCount = (bitmapBytesPerRow * size.height);


    cacheBitmap = malloc( bitmapByteCount );

        cacheBitmapSwiped= malloc( bitmapByteCount );


    ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate (cacheBitmap, size.width, size.height, 8,   bitmapBytesPerRow, CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst);

        //for finger sweaping
       cacheContextSwiped = CGBitmapContextCreate (cacheBitmapSwiped, size.width,      size.height, 8, bitmapBytesPerRow, CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst);

    return YES;
}



//method which draw a line on TouchesEND action

- (void) drawLine:(id)sender {

    UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0];

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, [color CGColor]);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 4);

    //outArray:array which holds cgpoints
    if ([outArray count] > 0)
    {

        CGPoint point1  = [(NSValue *)[[outArray objectAtIndex:[outArray count] -1 ] objectAtIndex: 0] CGPointValue];
        CGPoint point2  = [(NSValue *)[[outArray objectAtIndex:[outArray count] -1 ] objectAtIndex: 1] CGPointValue];


        ///ADDON
        CGRect rectPoint1 = CGRectMake(point1.x-10, point1.y-10, 20, 20);
        CGRect rectPoint2 = CGRectMake(point2.x-10, point2.y-10, 20, 20);
        CGRect newRect = CGRectUnion(rectPoint1, rectPoint2);

        ///ADD NEW CHECK
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(newRect, point1) && CGRectContainsPoint(newRect, point2))             {    
            CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, point1.x, point1.y);
            CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, point2.x, point2.y);
            CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
    }


        [self setNeedsDisplayInRect:newRect];

    }    

}

//method which draws lines on TouchesMoved action
//draw in rect

-(void)drawLineSwiped:(id)sender{

    //size of main image RECT
    CGSize mainImageRectSize = mainImageRect.size;

    int bitmapByteCount;
    int bitmapBytesPerRow;

    // Declare the number of bytes per row. Each pixel in the bitmap in this
    // example is represented by 4 bytes; 8 bits each of red, green, blue, and
    // alpha.
    bitmapBytesPerRow = (mainImageRectSize.width * 4);
    bitmapByteCount = (bitmapBytesPerRow * mainImageRectSize.height);

    // Allocate memory for image data. This is the destination in memory
    // where any drawing to the bitmap context will be rendered.
    //bitmap data


    //bitmap data for finger sweaped
    cacheBitmapSwiped= malloc( bitmapByteCount );


    //for finger sweaping
    cacheContextSwiped = CGBitmapContextCreate (cacheBitmapSwiped, mainImageRectSize.width, mainImageRectSize.height, 8, bitmapBytesPerRow, CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst);


    UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0];

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(cacheContextSwiped, [color CGColor]);
   CGContextSetLineWidth(cacheContextSwiped, 2);

    if ([outArray count] > 0)
    {

        CGPoint point1  = [(NSValue *)[[outArray objectAtIndex:[outArray count] -1 ] objectAtIndex: 0] CGPointValue];
        CGPoint point2  = [(NSValue *)[[outArray objectAtIndex:[outArray count] -1 ] objectAtIndex: 1] CGPointValue];


        CGRect rectPoint1 = CGRectMake(point1.x-10, point1.y-10, 20, 20);
        CGRect rectPoint2 = CGRectMake(point2.x-10, point2.y-10, 20, 20);

        CGRect newRect = CGRectUnion(rectPoint1, rectPoint2);

        if (CGRectContainsPoint(newRect, lastPoint1) && CGRectContainsPoint(newRect, newPoint)) {
            //draw line into the screen

            CGContextMoveToPoint(cacheContextSwiped, point1.x, point1.y);
            CGContextAddLineToPoint(cacheContextSwiped, point2.x, point2.y);
            CGContextStrokePath(cacheContextSwiped);

        }


        free(cacheBitmapSwiped);


        [self setNeedsDisplayInRect:newRect];


    }    



}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {


    context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();


    if (mouseEnded) {
        CGImageRef cacheImage;
        cacheImage= CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);
        CGContextDrawImage(context, self.bounds, cacheImage);
        CGImageRelease(cacheImage);
   }

    else if(mouseSwiped ){

        CGImageRef cacheImageSwiped;

        cacheImageSwiped= CGBitmapContextCreateImage(cacheContextSwiped);
        CGContextDrawImage(context, self.bounds, cacheImageSwiped);
        CGImageRelease(cacheImageSwiped);
    }
```

Also i have to say that i have a method(add cgpoints in outArray) which is running in TouchesBegan, TouchesMoved, TouchesEnded.

So i tried to draw a line during the finger's movement(also removes the previous line during movement), but the underlying(or previous -ended- lines) were disappeared from my screen. I tried also to add a subview during finger movement(in this model) and simultaneously remove the previous subview but also adds a lag in application.

The situation in drawing is too confused for me until now. In android the is a method which draws (onDraw) and this method updates the view and no overwrites it(with invalidate() call) . 
have you something to suggest? i have to repeat that i would like to draw the 1200th line with good performance without (optical ) delays.
thanx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5693297/how-to-draw-wavy-line-on-ios-device

Answer (score 0):

The first optimization you should do is to only redraw the area that needs updating. Instead of `setNeedsDisplay` in `touchesMoved:withEvent:`, calculate the area you need to update (basically a rect that includes the two last touch locations) and call `setNeedsDisplayInRect:` with this area.

Then, in your `for` loop in `drawRect:`, determine whether any given shape falls into this rectangle and only draw it if it does.

Comment: Hello Ole, thank you very much for your response. i tried something above. thanx again. i am looking forward for your feedback.:)