# How do I draw wavy lines in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, drawing, line

Is it possible to draw a set of wavy lines in JavaScript or using a JavaScript library? My question is somewhat [similar to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5693297/how-to-draw-wavy-line-on-ios-device), but I have to use JavaScript instead of Objective-C.

To expand more on my question, I want to draw a sequence of three or more lines.

```
------------------------------
------------------------------
------------------------------
```

But instead of being straight, I want the lines to produce random curves that cause them to overlap with one another.

Comment: `~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~`

Comment: you can draw on a canvas tag. you need to loop the X axis while you rotate/wobble a range of 3 Y values. see http://matt.might.net/articles/rendering-mathematical-functions-in-javascript-with-canvas-html/ for a flexible yet simple implementation to modify.

Comment: Alternatively to Canvas you could try SVG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using html5 canvas with bezierCurveTo method. Though it won't work in browsers which do not support html5.

```
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(20,70);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(100,10,150,100,200,20);
ctx.stroke();
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PLJ89/

Here is documentation for bezierCurveTo method http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_beziercurveto.asp